# USB tethering: interface not recognized

Tags: arch-linux, usb, ethernet, android

I try establishing USB tethering between my phone (Android 2.3) and my laptop (Antergos) by following [the related article on ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/android_tethering)

However, when I use command 'ip link' (as it is mentioned in the guide at point 2: USB tethering) only 3 connections are shown: lo, wlp3s0, enp0s25

It is the same when the phone is connected, indicating that my laptop is unable to recognize the shared connection.

I've found no method for solving it so far - even stranger: regular access to my phone's memory card is entirely possible.

What can be the reason, and how can I solve this issue?

(EDIT: tethering is obviously turned on in any case in which I tried - connection is still not recognized)

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: No, got a new phone since so I don't have this issue anymore. Maybe it was hardware-specific.